# Variable or field 'psort' declared void

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, g++

I'm getting this error when I try to compile:

```
psort.cpp:11:17: error: variable or field ‘psort’ declared void
void psort(std::vector<T> * array)
```

I'm not really sure why I'm getting this. I read through a few other posts about the same error but they didn't really help me at all.

```
/**
 * @file psort.h
 */

#ifndef _PSORT_H_
#define _PSORT_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <omp.h>

using std::vector;

namespace ParallelSort
{
/**
 * Public wrapper for the parallel sort implementation.
 * @param array The structure to sort
 */
template <class T>
void psort(vector<T> * array);

template <class T>
vector<T> * mergeSort(vector<T> * array, int left, int right);

template <class T>
vector<T> * merge(vector<T> * arr1, vector<T> * arr2);

}

#include "psort.cpp"
#endif
```

and here's the .cpp :

```
template <class T>
void psort(vector<T> * array)
{

mergeSort(array, 0, array->size() - 1);

}

template <class T>
vector<T> * mergeSort(vector<T> * array, int left, int right) {

if (left >= right) {

    return array;

}

int midpoint = (left + right) / 2;

return merge(mergeSort(array, left, midpoint - 1), mergeSort(array, midpoint, right));

}

template <class T>
vector<T> * merge(vector<T> * arr1, vector<T> * arr2) {

vector<T> * result();
result->resize(arr1->size() + arr2->size());

int i = 0; // result array position
int j = 0; // arr1 position
int k = 0; // arr2 position

while (i <result->size() ) {

    if (j >= arr1->size()) {

        result[i] = arr2[k];
        i++;
        k++;

    } else if (k >= arr2->size()) {

        result[i] = arr1[j];
        i++;
        j++;

    } else if (arr1[j] <= arr2[k]) {

        result[i] = arr1[j];
        i++;
        j++;

    } else if (arr2[k] <= arr1[j]) {

        result[i] = arr2[k];
        i++;
        k++;

    }

}

return result;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using
#include "psort.cpp"
in the end of your header file? It's not nesessary and may cause problems.

Comment: It was part of the given outline, therefore I didn't change it. Regardless, it's not the cause of my problem.

Comment: It isn't? It sure would be if you tried to compile `psort.cpp` as a translation unit entry point, and i see zero evidence that *isn't* being done. What is including `psort.h` ?

Comment: @KostyaVerhun: It is necessary, and the file should more properly be named `psort.impl` or similar to avoid this kind of confusion. The source file contains template function definitions, but declares no explicit implementations, so the program would fail to link if this source file were not `#include`d. (To clarify: By "implementation," I mean putting stuff like `template<> void psort<int>(vector<int>*);` in the `.cpp` file to support `T = int`, for all `T` to be supported.)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is because your CPP file contents are not inside a namespace.

In the header file you close the namespace which is correct. So to put the function definitions into that namespace you need to open it again.

Comment: +1 Why do I get the feeling the "solution" to this is going to be to move `#include "psort.cpp"` *inside* the namespace braces in the header file. Ugh.